# What does it mean if a number has a remainder of 1?

Tags: arithmetic

I have this problem:

```
linesize = 20

counter % linesize == 1 // what does this line mean?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means the the variable `counter` is of the form $x.20 +1 (x \in \mathbb{N})$ or in other words, counter is One more than a multiple of 20 (21,41,61 etc.)

Comment: One should be careful about this. If `counter` is negative then your statement is false, as most programming languages have the `%` operator return a result of the same sign as the first argument.